# Today's date in outlook template

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

Is there any way to insert today's date in outlook's template subject or body? Such that whenever I open the saved template, today's date should be automatically shown in subject and body.

Is there any inbuilt function? something like Date() ?

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Templates don't provide anything for that.

Instead, you may consider creating a VBA macro or add-in. In the [NewInspector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867841(v=office.15).aspx) or [Active](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865363(v=office.15).aspx) event you can check out the CurrentItem property of the Inspector class - whether it is a new item and created using a template. Typically new Outlook items don't have the EntryID property set. And then insert the current date wherever you need.